# Passing DateTime variables into SQL Server stored procedures in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 that looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[REP_PayRange]
    @StartDate datetime = NULL,
    @EndDate datetime = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT * FROM Payment WHERE PayTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
END
```

It executes and I get results from within SQL by running:

```
EXEC REP_PayRange '1 Jan 2012', '10 Jan 2012'
```

The place I'm having difficulty is in Visual Studio.

Here are the steps I'm taking:

1. Create a new, blank, "Web Form"/aspx page with the Visual Basic language selected
2. Insert a GridView
3. Choose a datasource and select "Database"
4. Choose a Data Connection that I have confirmed works (SQL Server Native)
5. "Specify a custom SQL statement or stored procedure"
6. Select "Stored Procedure:" "REP_PayRange"
7. Choose "Parameter source: None" and Default Value "1 Jan 2012" for StartDate and "Parameter source: None" and Default Value "10 Jan 2012" for EndDate
8. On the Test Query page I hit "Test Query", make sure my values are what I specified above and no data is returned.  If I save this and preview it in the browser the GridView is empty.

I'd like to create my webpage using this method so that I can later change my parameter source to a calendar rather than the default values.

Thank you in advance for any help or tips.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

(a) stop formatting your strings with regional, language-dependent styles. Use a proper, standard, unambiguous format, like `'YYYYMMDD'`. Your web form should be passing properly typed parameters and/or use `.Format()` to get rid of this '1 Jan 2012' nonsense.

(b) stop using `BETWEEN` for date range queries, as this can be quite ambiguous (even when you think your datetime column does not contain time, are you sure between means what you think it does)?

Some background:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: HI Aaron, Thanks for your time.  I've now tried with the format you recommended and it still works in SQL but Visual Studio tells me that the "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" See [here](http://imgur.com/UQwMT).


The reason I used "between" was to provide a simple example of how to recreate the problem.  It still doesn't explain why it works in SQL but not visual studio.


Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, don't know, have not used that parameter values dialog once in my life. Perhaps that hokey thing is expecting quotes around it (e.g. `'20100101'`) or perhaps it needs `'yyyy-mm-dd'`...

Comment: Ah, well I just tried 'yyyy-mm-dd' and visual studio accepted it as a valid input but the SQL query returned no results.  Maybe I'll have to learn how to do this the manual way.  The funny thing is that if you define it as a custom SQL Statement in Visual Studio (exec REP_PayRange '01 Jan 2012', '10 Jan 2012') it returns a value but then you can't use the handy parameter source chooser.